# warning on if statement to find and replace values using match in R

Tags: r, if-statement, warnings, match

I'm new to R. I'm trying to write an if statment to replace an infrequent value in a dataframe with values from another dataframe, based on a match between two other variables in these dataframes. My code is this:

```
if(myData$Region == 'Head Office'){
myData$Region <- LocationData$Region[match(myData$Township,LocationData$Township)]
}
```

R returns: 
`Warning message:
In if (myData$Region == "Head Office") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Which I hope means the code works, but only for the first row of data. Based on other SO questions, I tried

```
ifelse(myData$Region == 'Head Office'){
myData$Region <- LocationData$Region[match(myData$Township,LocationData$Township)],
}
```

But it returns mutiple errors.

My question: Is the `if` statement likely to work for this purpose?  Do I just need to figure out the proper syntax to make it run through all rows in `myData`, or is this the wrong approach altogether?

Comment: Have you read the help for `ifelse`?

Comment: I did, for `if` as well.  I couldn't relate the examples provided to my code, no doubt because I barely understand them.  I did also try using `ifelse` with two different specified outcomes for false: first I left it blank, which i thought meant if false do nothing, and I tried specifying it as the original value, which i thought meant if false write in original value.

Comment: I also tried adding `for(i in 1:length(myData$Region))` which returned the same warning a whole bunch of times, instead of just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax on your ifelse is incorrect, and there is a missing "else" value

```
?ifelse
```

Assuming your "else" value is myData$Region,

```
myData$Region <- ifelse(myData$Region == 'Head Office',
       LocationData$Region[match(myData$Township,LocationData$Township)],
       myData$Region)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - with the proper syntax the code is now working (result is not as expected, but hey, progress!). I can see now why @mnel recommended a closer look at the help file.  I thought I needed the curly brackets for looping, and didn't understand why the help file didn't show them as an option.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this problem...the `ifelse` code ran after the syntax was corrected as suggest by @luis_js, but it was not returning the result I needed: conditionally replacing a value for mydata$Region, with a value from LocationData$Region, based on a match for Township, a column found in both dataframes.

I tried the "more R like" solution suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921344/if-statement-to-replace-nas-in-a-column-matching-with-a-different-column-from-an?rq=1 - and it works perfectly.

For my data, the code to perform the conditional replace is

```
headoffice <- myData$Region == 'Head Office'
myData$Region[headoffice] <- LocationData$Region[match(myData$Township[headoffice],LocationData$Township)]
```